# using easybmat and tikz packages together?

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, matrices

In continuation to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/how-to-typeset-block-matrices) question, I was looking for a way to add nice diagonal lines inside a BMAT matrix to express a band structure of the matrix. However, a LaTeX file with both TikZ and easybmat fails to compile.

Is there anything I could do to have these two packages compile together?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%\usepackage{easybmat}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
This document fails to compile if you remove both percent
signs. Remove any one of them and it compiles fine.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `\usepackage{etex}`

Comment: I’m curious: why does this help?

Comment: this package "modifies LaTeX\u2019s register 
allocation macros to make use of the extended register range." In the above example, as far as I can understand there is a lack of memory allocation for "dimen". My answer relies more on experience than understanding. Experts are welcome to comment.

Comment: Great answer! succinct, correct and fast! Go TeX.SE!

Comment: Just to make this answer more complete: the order of the packages seems to have to be: easybmat,etex, tikz.

Comment: While the package works, the alignment is screwy unless one uses the settings given in this solution to a different question of mine: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/how-to-get-tikz-nodes-not-to-change-alignment/3721#3721