# Using `easybmat` and `beamer` together

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I've written an article using the `easybmat` package and now it is time to create the `beamer` slides....however, as you can see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3439/using-easybmat-and-tikz-packages-together), in order to load both the `easybmat` and `tikz` (or `pgf`?) one needs to **first** load the `etex` package. This I do not know how to do in the `beamer` documentclass where the most minimal example fails:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{beamer}

\usepackage{easybmat} % I get different errors depending  
\usepackage{etex}     % on the order of these two lines 

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Do I need to resort to \LoadClass solutions? (I so, I need help...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've already encountered this bug once. Here are two solutions to solve the problem; the first is quick and easy to put in place, while the second needs to look at where the problem occurs.

**SOLUTION 1.** It is possible to load packages before `\documentclass` by using `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage`. This allows to get both `etex` and `easybmat` loaded before `tikz` and makes the problem disappear:

```
\RequirePackage{etex}
\RequirePackage{easybmat}
\documentclass[beamer]{beamer}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

**SOLUTION 2.** Loading `easybmat` first and then `etex` cannot work because there won't be enough `dimen` registers available for `easybmat`. So you must load `etex` first and  `easybmat` second. The error message becomes `You can't use a prefix with '\begingroup'`. The reason for this error is due to both `easybmat.sty` and `etex.sty`. The problem with `easybmat.sty` is that it calls the package `easy.sty` which declares some new dimensions with `\global\newdimen`. Putting a `\global` before `\newdimen` is not necessary but is usually harmless. Here, however, it is not harmless because `etex.sty` is loaded **and** (the two conditions must be met) the `\newdimen` with the `\global` occurs when `etex.sty` switches between the vanilla TeX registers and the extended eTeX engine ones. The reason can be found in the code of the `\alloc@` macro from `etex.sty` which has a `\begingroup` in it. What happens is that the `\global` before `\newdimen` gets applied to this `\begingroup`, thus triggering the error. A (not very elegant) way to solve the problem is to put a dummy definition just before the `\begingroup`. It should not (I hope) have any side effects.

```
\documentclass[beamer]{beamer}

\usepackage{etex}
\makeatletter
\def\alloc@#1#2#3#4#5%
 {\ifnum\count1#1<#4% make sure there's still room
    \allocationnumber\count1#1
    \global\advance\count1#1\@ne
    \global#3#5\allocationnumber
    \wlog{\string#5=\string#2\the\allocationnumber}%
  \else\ifnum#1<6
    \def\etex@dummy@definition{}% <-- code added
    \begingroup \escapechar\m@ne
    \expandafter\alloc@@\expandafter{\string#2}#5%
  \else\errmessage{No room for a new #2}\fi\fi
 }
\makeatother
\usepackage{easybmat}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works!! Thanks. Is this a bug? In what package? are you going to report it with you nifty workaround?

Comment: @Philippe: Your second solution looks really nice! Maybe you can edit your answer to give this easy solution first? I think this would be very helpful!

Comment: @ Hendrik: I've put the easiest solution first as well as expanded a little the explanations of the second. @Yossi: It might be considered a bug in `etex`, but the problem is really with `easybmat` which should not use `\global` before `\newdimen`. I'll try to report the problem, but I'm not sure the `easybmat` package is still actively maintained or that a hack as a dummy definition would be acceptable in a common package like `etex`.

Comment: There's been some discussion of this issue on the LaTeX-L list  in the context of the `etex` package.

Comment: @Philippe: +1, great, looks much better now. (By the way, I didn't get notified of your comment due to the space after "@". But only this way Yossi was notified: You can only notify _one_ user with "@".)

Comment: @Joseph: I suppose you're referring to http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.latex.latex3/2141 Did you have time to try to work around the problem?

Comment: @Philippe: Will fixed the issue you reference `fontspec` a few weeks ago, by switching to `expl3` code for the section in question.