# You can't use a prefix with `\begingroup' error with Tex live 2013

Tags: errors

Minimum not working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times New Roman
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{hyperref} % clickable links
\usepackage{float} % for fixed floats (H)
\usepackage{subcaption} % figures side-by-side
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry} % nice margins
\usepackage{booktabs} % midrule etc
\usepackage{microtype} % better justification; always use with pdflatex!
\usepackage{siunitx} % for scientific notation AND units!

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Log says:

```
...
! You can't use a prefix with `\begingroup'.
<to be read again>
\begingroup
l.14 \begin{document}
I'll pretend you didn't say \long or \outer or \global or \protected.
Normal \count register pool exhausted, switching to extended pool.
...
```

This occurs with pdflatex version `Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)` but doesn't occur with `Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)`

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you post the entire log. Besides, that is an old latex  and miktex 2.9 must be assumed to the never

Comment: @daleif The entire log is too long to post, the relevant part should be there

Comment: that was a bug in etex.sty  if you do not want to update the packages try adding `\usepackage{etex}` as early as possible.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle unfortunately, I already tried that, it didn't fix it. Also the I forgot to mention that the error disappears when I leave out any one of the listed packages

Comment: compiled in my debian VM without error. and I'm using an even older version `Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)`

Comment: Maybe you can try the fix proposed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5999/4427

Comment: Thanks, I already tried some of those methods without luck. I have decided to update my tex environment. (But sadly, I am making a template, which I might want to share with other people, and it would have been good to be backwards-compatible.)

Comment: I noticed commenting `\usepackage{float}` removes error.  So, then I tried adding `\usepackage{floatflt}` along with `\usepackage{float}`, now  the document is error free for me.