# Writing Some Special Matrices in LaTeX

Tags: matrices

I've to write the following matrices in LaTex.

[image: Matrices]

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40/how-do-i-label-different-rows-or-columns-of-a-matrix-using-braces and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/how-to-typeset-block-matrices for some closely related questions that have already been answered here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometnig like

```
\begin{equation}
 \bordermatrix{&c_1&c_2&c_3\cr
            r_1&t_{11}&t_{12}&t_{13}\cr
            r_2&t_{21}&t_{22}&t_{23}\cr
            r_3&t_{31}&t_{32}&t_{33}\cr}
\end{equation}
```

?

This will give you c's and r's outside the t_nn matrix.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesn't my purpose. I've also looked at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40/how-do-i-label-different-rows-or-columns-of-a-matrix-using-braces. But struggling to get it write.